# Highcharts dual axes navigator

Tags: highcharts, navigator

I've started to use a graphic pretty similar to the dual combo axes. I've added the navigator from highstocks but the navigator graphic differs a lot from the graphic. 
It seems that the navigator is plotting both series on the same column and I'm not capable of configuring both axis for it.

I'm trying to modify the jsfiddle example but I couldn't make it work:

```
series: [{
        name: 'Rainfall',
        type: 'column',
        yAxis: 1,
        data: [49.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4],
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: ' mm'
        },
        showInNavigator: true

    }, {
        name: 'Temperature',
        type: 'spline',
        data: [7.0, 6.9, 9.5, 14.5, 18.2, 21.5, 25.2, 26.5, 23.3, 18.3, 13.9, 9.6],
        tooltip: {
            valueSuffix: '°C'
        },
        showInNavigator: true
    }]
```

http://jsfiddle.net/guconnmn/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a **workaround** for the problem that **ewolden** pointed out:

> I did not find a way to put each series on its own axis in the
>   navigator.

You can compute the ratio of the both y axes maximums and than update all the points in the second series using new values. That should mimic the presence of the second y axis.

```
chart: {
    zoomType: 'x',
    events: {
      load: function() {
        var chart = this,
          navigator = chart.navigator,
          ratio = chart.yAxis[0].getExtremes().max / chart.yAxis[1].getExtremes().max;


        navigator.series[1].points.forEach(function(p) {
          p.update({
            y: p.y / ratio
          });
        }, false);

        this.redraw();
      }
    }
  }
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/kkulig/p44kx9xn/

Comment: This what exactly what I was looking for!

 I ended up improving it using:

`ratio1 = chart.yAxis[0].getExtremes().max + chart.yAxis[0].getExtremes().m`
`ratio2 = chart.yAxis[1].getExtremes().max + chart.yAxis[1].getExtremes().min;`

Answer (score 0):

You can add both graphs to the navigator using the following code:

```
navigatorOptions: {
  type: 'column' //in the column series
}
```

And

```
navigatorOptions: {
  type: 'line' //in the line series
}
```

That said, I did not find a way to put each series on its own axis in the navigator. Furthermore, highstock does not support `xAxis` `categories`, [see API](https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/xAxis), `highstock.xAxis` only supports datetime format. So you will have to fill in timestamps and format them to show months if that is your desired output.

**Working example:** http://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/p5amaofc/

**API on series.navigatorOptions:** https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/series.line.navigatorOptions